# Access entity within Lift Scala net.liftweb.util.Box object

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, lift

I have a net.liftweb.util.Box object which is returned as a result of a search on a user id. The box object returns something like:

```
net.liftweb.util.Box[MyEntity{attributes}]
```

How can I access the entity within the Box? In particular, I want to access the attributes of the entity inside the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see http://lift.la/scala-option-lift-box-and-how-to-make-your-co

You can access the contents of a Box within a foreach/map method invocation.  For example if you wanted to get the name out of your entity:

```
myBoxedEntity.map(_.name) openOr "No Name Provided"
```

If the Box is Full, you'll get the entity name otherwise, you'll get the message.

Comment: How would you unbox a complete object, instead of just a field. Say for example you wanted to create a new arbitrary object based on the fields of the returned object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want execute some operation on the object on box dmap is helpful.

For example:

```
fooBox.dmap("Yo!")(foo => 
  // dome some staff with foo 
  result // must be string
)
```

You can get the element directly by calling fooBox.open_! but it's not recommended. It often raises null pointer exception when box is empty.